# Extract object encapsulated state through NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

## Context

I'm maintaining a WPF application which applies DDD principles. A strong focus has been made on encapsulating state (=making fields private as much as possible).
The state of the aggregates are persisted into an SQLite database with the help of NHibernate. Mappings are declared with the help of FluentNHibernate.
No other application is accessing the database.

## Problem

I'm facing a new requirement which is that a specific aggregate has to be accessible through multiple instances of the same application running on different computers in the same LAN.

## Envisioned solution

I know there are many possible solutions (object DB, serialization through DTO, file sharing, etc.). But all of these necessitate a lot of new work in order to set something up.

Before I implement a new way to extract this state, I'd like to have more insights of the possibility to use a feature that is baked into NHibernate:

In order to persist the aggregate, NHibernate is able (with the help of the mapping, custom user types and a lot of reflection) to extract primitive values (string, int, decimal, etc.) in order to inject them into SQL queries so that they are persisted.

Does it exist a way to intercept these raw values somewhere so that I can do something else with them ? Basically my idea summarizes as using NHibernate not only to persist the state locally but also to get a "serialized" version of this state (without any additional configuration or mapping) so that I can send it over the wire and hydrate the same object on the other end (doing the inverse process with the help of NHibernate too).

So far, after looking at the bits of NH I found the track of `EntityEntry.LoadedState` which could contain the information I'm looking for. Could this be suitable for my needs ?
How could I:

1. Retrieve that property for my desired aggregate ?
2. Hydrate my aggregate from that property ?

---

Following David Osborne's answer, I already have the 'entry point' which defines the **when** in the form of a domain event handler:

```
public class SaveCommittedOrderClosed : IDomainEventHandler<CommittedOrderClosed>
{
    public Result<Unit, Error> Handle(IUnitOfWork uow, CommittedOrderClosed @event)
    {
        //Could I use NH here to extract some state from @event.Order ?
    }
}
```

What I lack the knowledge of is the **how**.

Answer (score 1):

How about an [event listener](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html)? This will give you the 'entry point' at which you could do the other actions.

Comment: I didn't know about the event system in NH however my problem is not **when** (I already have what you called the entry point) but **how** to use NH (see my edit for details).

Comment: Does the `@event.Order` property have everything you need, or do you need to go elsewhere to get some more data?

Comment: `@event.Order` is my aggregate root. All the state I need is encapsulated in there.

Comment: So what more do you need at this point?

Comment: To extract the state from my aggregate root, which is almost entirely private. I could use some reflection but since NH is already doing it for the persistence my idea was to reuse the work NH already does but to achieve another goal.